# Titanium Database creation

Tags: titanium-mobile

I  need to create an database like using android SqliteOpenHelper Database creation over Titanium development. How to create and run db on runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is extremely well documented, did you not check the docs / google it first?

- Here is the long but very good tutorial by Appcelerator : [Appcelerator DB Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/Working_with_a_SQLite_Database)
- Here is a video tutorial on local data by Appcelerator, if you dont like to read. [Titanium Local Storage](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/video/Working%20with%20Local%20Data)
- Here is a shorter tutorial on a blog: [Labrum.co Tutorial](http://labrum.co/articles/titanium/using-a-local-database-with-titanium/)
- And here is the actual documentation which is more than adequate to get started : [Titanium.Database](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Database)
- Finally, here is a common misconception about databases in the form of a Q&A session. [Q&A](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/3431/basic-question-about-titaniumdatabase)

Comment: Is it also applied to the Alloy structure? Once I tried all these 5 tutorials, then I'm gonna proceed new database test using with NodeJS for mobile.

Comment: Same docs apply to Alloy as well. BUt Alloy data abstractions (Models, Collections with Backbone.js) make it easier to use.